# Is it possible to write a script that run su or sudo command without typing password?

Tags: sudo, su

Is it possible to write a script that run `su` or `sudo` command without typing password?. I googled and its said that `su` doesn't read password from buffer. So is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches as far as I can tell:

### Good idea

When setting up `sudo` for a specific user or group, you can use the `ALL=NOPASSWD` option in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Some pointers on how to do that:

- [How to setup passwordless `sudo` on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/160581)
- [How to enable passwordless sudo in Linux](https://docs.oseems.com/general/operatingsystem/linux/enable-passwordless-sudo)

### Bad idea

You can use `sudo` with the `-S` option to give the password through standard input instead of the terminal device.  For example, you can write down the password in a file, and then do `cat myPass.txt | sudo -S your_command`.

Comment: So, having your user use passwordless sudo is "best"? Or barring that, Assuming that keeping a password in plain text would  be bad, you'll need a user who can use passwordless sudo, then you'll have to log in as that user? Any easy way to do that without it being insecure?

Comment: Setting it in the `sudoers` list would be the *secure* way, in my opinion.  Having passwords in plain text out there is always a bad idea, but I just wanted to let the OP know that it can be done, whether it's a good or a bad idea...

Comment: Also, I think the `sudoers` list can be setup to allow one specific command to be run.  Take a look at [**this**](http://www.atrixnet.com/allow-an-unprivileged-user-to-run-a-certain-command-with-sudo/) and [**this**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Comment: Specific command "nopwd" sudo sounds the best. Just trying to log in as another user, without keeping that user's pw in plain text is the same problem as not keeping your own (sudo) password in plain text. Unless logging in as the other user with ssh keys or something over complicated

Comment: I would definitely recommend the `NOPASSWD` approach over putting the password in a file.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it clear that using passwords in plain text files is not a good idea :)  thanks for your comments!

Comment: @jim Instead of using su or sudo from a normal user.  set setuid flag on the script.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid . So after you've created the script, change the owner to root, for example `chown root:buadmins myscript` , and give the appropriate execute permissions, for example `chmod 755`.  Then set uid, for example `chmod ug+s myscript` Then when the user runs the script it will run as root.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect` for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set password "mypassword"
spawn sudo mkdir -v newdir
expect "Password:"
send -- "$password\n"
expect "mkdir: created directory 'newdir'"
```